# vb.net Integer variable names being ignored?

Tags: vb.net

For some reason my code is fine with the first Integer variable but ignores or does not handle the second Integer variable.

```
Dim sequentialInt As Integer = 1
Dim newSeqInt As Integer = 1
```

I am not violating a rule am I? I have restarted Visual Studio several times..

Mouse Hover-Over shows the value for `SequentialInt` but barfs and refuses to acknowledge the 2nd.

Comment: `barfs`. I'm not sure I've ever seen a `SystemBarfException` before. Perhaps there is a more technical method of describing the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: @JoelEtherton It litterally skips over it in Debug mode, and places the breakpoint 1 line under it.

Comment: this sounds like the IDE is not recognizing some kind of compiled change. Did you previously have code on that line in the file?

Comment: @JoelEtherton I didn't really I quite litterally replaced the file from backup and added the 2 variables again.. same problem.. moved them to the top of the class and same problem.

Comment: My recommendation would be to perform a `Clean Solution` and then `Rebuild All`. You may even need to close the IDE, delete everything in the `/bin` and `/obj` folders and try again.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - .. it is looking like I may need to clear the /bin and /obj folders

Answer (score 6):

Odds are that the code isn't getting compiled when you start debugging. So, you end up debugging an old version of the code and it looks like the debugger is going crazy (e.g. `SystemBarfException`). Go to Build --> Configuration Manager and ensure the "Build" check box is checked. Otherwise, manually forcing a build (CTRL-SHIFT-B) before debugging might also fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: For the record, I think I'm going to trademark the `SystemBarfException`. I might even have to sneak that type into my next project somewhere.

Comment: LOL! And the royalty checks will roll in...Absolutely brilliant! Maybe that one needs to go up to MS Connect for a .NET Futures Request.

Comment: +1 purely for the `SystemBarfException`. Why stop there though? I can see a need for `SystemWTF` and `SystemShitHappened` too.